# Errores con este codigo, que es lo que esta mal?

Tags: php, array

```
'asset_kind' => function($fields, $id) {

    $kind = get_post_field('asset_content_sections', $id);

    $fields = $kind['radio_kind'];

    return $fields;
},
```

Algunos de los errores:

> Undefined index: radio_kind
>
> Illegal string offset 'radio_kind'
>
> Uninitialized string offset: 0

Dump de la variable `$kind`:

```
"asset_kind": [ 
    { 
        "title": "das", 
        "content_blocks": [ 
            { 
                "content": " dsadad \n", 
                "radio_kind": "right" 
            } 
        ] 
    } 
]
```

Comment: Por lo que se ve, dice que el array `$kind` no tiene ningún índice llamado `"radio_kind"`. Lo que te recomiendo es que luego de crear la variable `$kind` hagas `var_dump($kind);` y veas qué contiene. O por lo menos nos lo indiques.

Comment: Esto es lo que devuelve la variable kind en la api

"asset_kind": [
          {
            "title": "das",
            "content_blocks": [
              {
                "content": "
dsadad
\n",
                "radio_kind": "right"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],

Comment: Osea que radio_king si existe por lo tanto el array deberia tener indice

Comment: No, para empezar eso que devolvió es JSON, tienes que transformarlo en un array con `json_decode()`, puedes leer sobre eso aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Es que estamos trabajando con una rest api y eso lo devuelve asi pero tecnicamente no es json

Comment: Probá el siguiente enlace: https://3v4l.org/EfO2N

Answer (score 0):

Deberías hacer algo así:

```
'asset_kind' => function($fields, $id) {

        $kind = json_decode(get_post_field('asset_content_sections', $id));

        $fields = $kind['content_blocks'][0]['radio_kind'];

        return $fields;
    },
```

Eso te ayuda a llegar a la clave que tu quieres, recuerda que estoy accediendo al 0 porque es un array.